# Batch resize and OUTPUT multiple images

Tags: image, batch-file, resize, photoshop, photoshop-script

I need to batch re-size multiple images and this is real easy in Photoshop insert a folder and get a output in another folder.

But I need multiple images of a single image.

What I have is a folder of all the original images and of every single image I need it in four differed sizes, see:

[image]

Comment: just do it four times, once for every size. what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is doing it four times

Comment: could you please elaborate more your question?

Comment: what is there to explain more i have one image and i need four, and i want to do this as efficient as possible

Comment: I think what PA is asking is, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?  Just to nudge you in a worthwhile direction, [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) supports [command-line switches](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options) for batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

This script will do what you want: Save out four images in the size required as gifs in a directory called "export"

```
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var imageWidth = srcDoc.width.value;
var imageHeight = srcDoc.height.value;
var resizeRes = 72;
fileName = app.activeDocument.name;
docName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.length -4);

//turn it RGB
var id60 = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id61 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
var id62 = charIDToTypeID( "RGBM" );
desc12.putClass( id61, id62 );
executeAction( id60, desc12, DialogModes.NO );

// create directory called export
var myExportDir = "export"
var myDirectoryName = srcDoc.path + "/" + myExportDir;
var myDirectory = new Folder(myDirectoryName);
if(!myDirectory.exists) myDirectory.create();

// define the array to hold the sizes of the shrunk images
var reSizeArr = [
   [125,  70,  ResampleMethod.BICUBIC],
   [640,  360, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC],
   [320,  180, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC],
   [1005, 565, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC],
      ]

for (var i=0; i<reSizeArr.length; i++)
   {
   var shrinkWidth =  reSizeArr [i][0];
   var shrinkHeight = reSizeArr [i][1];
   var mySaveName = shrinkWidth + "x" + shrinkHeight;
   var resizeMethod = reSizeArr [i][2];

   // duplicate image into new document
   // =======================================================
   var id428 = charIDToTypeID( "Dplc" );
   var desc92 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id429 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
   var ref27 = new ActionReference();
   var id430 = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
   var id431 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
   var id432 = charIDToTypeID( "Frst" );
   ref27.putEnumerated( id430, id431, id432 );
   desc92.putReference( id429, ref27 );
   var id433 = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
   desc92.putString( id433, mySaveName );
   executeAction( id428, desc92, DialogModes.NO );

   // resize image
   activeDocument.resizeImage(shrinkWidth, shrinkHeight, resizeRes, resizeMethod);

   // set to 256 cols
   var id111 = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
   var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id112 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
   var desc24 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id113 = charIDToTypeID( "Plt " );
   var id114 = charIDToTypeID( "ClrP" );
   var id115 = charIDToTypeID( "Exct" );
   desc24.putEnumerated( id113, id114, id115 );
   var id116 = charIDToTypeID( "FrcC" );
   var id117 = charIDToTypeID( "FrcC" );
   var id118 = charIDToTypeID( "None" );
   desc24.putEnumerated( id116, id117, id118 );
   var id119 = charIDToTypeID( "Trns" );
   desc24.putBoolean( id119, false );
   var id120 = charIDToTypeID( "IndC" );
   desc23.putObject( id112, id120, desc24 );
   executeAction( id111, desc23, DialogModes.NO );

   // Set filePath and fileName to source path
   filePath = srcDoc.path + "/" + myExportDir + "/" + mySaveName  + ".gif";

   // save out the image
   var gifFile = new File(filePath);
   gifSaveOptions = new GIFSaveOptions();
   gifSaveOptions.colors = 256;
   gifSaveOptions.dither = Dither.NONE;
   gifSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
   gifSaveOptions.preserveExactColors = 0;
   gifSaveOptions.transparency = 1;

   activeDocument.saveAs(gifFile, gifSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);

   // close that saved gif
    app.activeDocument.close()
   } 

   //close without saving
   app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```